# How to make a text with specified width and height be in center?

Tags: css

How can i make a text with specified width and height be in center? Not just horizontal.

Example:
`h1 {width: 200px; height: 36px; text-align:center;}`

but it give me something like this.

[image]

EDIT: I figure it out.

`line-height: 10px`

Comment: Can you post code for what you have tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Or perhaps have a look at this answer on vertical alignment in a div https://stackoverflow.com/a/2939979/15310387

Comment: You want text to be horizontally center(as per image)

Comment: @Yadab https://jsfiddle.net/4gvLyx7k/1/

Comment: @MrR Thank you. i figure out with line-height property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix it though top & bottom padding

```css
p{
   width: 200px;
   padding: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(69, 65, 62, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<p>$0.00 — $100.00 <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  Just remove text-align and use flex for dispalying item.

```css
p{
   width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(69, 65, 62, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<p>$0.00 — $100.00 <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></p>
```